# users resource in Puppet not updating /etc/shadow

Tags: users, ruby, puppet, shadow

I have written a manifests using `users` resource as shown below

```
node 'node2.example.com','node3.example.com'{
user {
       'ash':
 ensure  => 'present',
 managehome => 'true',
 comment => 'Zaman Home',
 home    => '/home/ash',
 shell   => '/bin/bash',
 expiry  => 'absent',
 password => '$1$cs1j/t.D$4qjZLwFQ2Ocr0pulyNTUx/',
 password_min_age => '30',
 password_max_age => '60'
```

}
}

The user is getting created successfully as shown below from `/etc/passwd`

```
ash:x:503:503:Zaman Home:/home/ash:/bin/bash
```

But the issue for me is that `/etc/shadow` is not getting updated 
.
    ash:!!:16875:0:99999:7:::

I have got ruby-shadow package installed.

```
# ruby -e "require 'puppet' ; puts Puppet.features.libshadow?"
true
```

Version are as follows:

```
 # ruby --version
 ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
 # puppet --version
 3.8.5
```

Please suggest

Comment: ok...This is resolved for me...I installed  ruby-shadow on only master nodes. Installed ruby-shadown on all client nodes and restarted puppet agent to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ruby-shadow` should be installed on all `hosts` which are being managed using puppet. Verify it is loaded properly by running the below command.

```
#ruby -e "require 'puppet' ; puts Puppet.features.libshadow?"
true
```

The package is available for download from the following location

http://pkgs.repoforge.org/ruby-shadow/